# Simple Oscillator Designs

Tags: oscillator, inverter

I want to be able to create simple oscillator circuits for clocking in digital circuits and am wondering what is the most simple design people know of?

I could use a simple ring oscillator which is pretty simple

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvRXIm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but this would run way quicker than I want - ideally looking to hit around 0.1Hz to 10Hz.

At the moment I have been using a bi-stable oscillator like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3qGiy.png)</sup>

This works well and I can control the frequency by varying the capacitor and resistor values, I am just wondering if there are better/simpler schemes? Specifically I'd like ones without the passives, but not using anything more complicated than basic logic (NOT, NAND, NOR etc).

Any contributions/ideas would be great, thanks!

Comment: The simplest design I know of is to use an SI501 chip.

Comment: You can't do an oscillator without any form of capacitor or inductor, but sometimes the parasitic capacitance inherent in a gate is enough. But unless specifically designed as such (inside a chip) it won't be very stable. I'd go for a 555 or HC4060. Or (in a funny mood, or for better accuracy) for a small microcontroler with internal oscillator.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle Your [**SI501**](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si501-2-3.pdf)  comment is an utterly inappropriate one for this person and it is clear that it does not address his query and is not intended to be useful. What is your intention here ?

Comment: To suggest an alternative that is industrially acceptable instead of "rolling your own", which while an admirable exersize for a learner is not something you would do when designing a real product.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle: I think you missed the frequency range the OP is looking for. The SI501 does not fit the bill.

Comment: @DaveTweed You're right there - a brief throwaway comment mentioning the desired speed - a speed which is ridiculously slow ;)  So an SI501 and some frequency dividers then :P

Comment: If you're circuit happens to be powered by a low voltage 60hZ fed supply, you might get away with a pretty simple and cheap clock source using a 4017 "Johnson counter" IC. You'd feed this IC's input clock pin from your low voltage AC source, through a resistor, maybe 20K. The chip's internal clamping diodes will condition the signal for you. A 4017 basically sequences outputs on 10 of its pins with each pulse, so any of those output pins will deliver 1/10 of the 60hZ, or 10hZ. As a bonus, you'll have a clock that's consistent, predictable, and sufficiently accurate to keep time.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle: Levity may be fine in other genres, but as I've been reminded often, this is not the place for it.  That, and what appears to be a rather flippant and arrogant attitude on your part is rather disturbing; particularly hearing that the OP's requirement for a particular range of clock frequencies is "ridiculously low."

Comment: @Randy 60Hz/10 = 6Hz. :)

Comment: If you eliminate the discrete passives **and** anything but a modicum of simple logic gates, I think you'll be left with an unobtainable goal for the frequency range you mention. In practical terms, what can you live with?

Comment: @EMFields Woops! :-) Oh well. Wish all my math errors ended up right in the middle of the spec like that!!! :-)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the passives? The passives are quite literally the simplest oscillator possible, it comes first in any electronics textbook. the RC oscillator. You can even just use a single gate if you make it a schmitt triggered one like the 74HC14 like as follows. http://i.stack.imgur.com/hVDnt.png

Logic gates are "infinitely fast" compared to the frequency range you are looking for, you need to slow down the signal propegation somehow and it doesn't get simpler than an RC delay for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use passive components, here is an all digital solution.  I realize using the counter chips goes beyond your desire to use only basic logic gates (NAND, NOR etc.), and indeed one can construct the counters used below from these elements, but the complexity would make it impractical.

Take your first oscillator, and add two more inverters.  The typical propagation delay t<sub>tpd</sub> of a [74HCT04 inverter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hct04.pdf) is 14 ns.  This will result in an output frequency of approximately 70 MHz (which I simulated in CircuitLab).  The reason for using  the lower frequency is two-fold; it allows a greater choice in parts for dividing down (for example the 74HC4024 part below has a maximum frequency of 90 MHz), and 70 MHz divides down closer to 1 Hz than 120 MHz using binary counters.

Using a [74HC4024 7-stage ripple counter](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC4024.pdf), use the Q4 tap to divide the 70 MHz by 32, giving a frequency of approximately 2.19 MHz.

Then using a [CD4521 24-stage counter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4521b.pdf), use the Q18 tap to divide 2.19 MHz by 262144 giving a frequency of 8.34 Hz.  Using the tap Q21, dividing 2.19 MHz by 2097152 generates 1.04 Hz. Using the last tap Q24, dividing 2.19 MHz by 16777216 give 0.13 Hz.

So, not quite the full range you asked for (0.1 to 10 Hz), but close (0.13 to 8.34 Hz, including 1 Hz almost exactly), and there are an additional four taps in between that can be used.

This would take three IC's -- the five inverters in one 74HCT04, and the two counters.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would **strongly** suggest using a CPLD for this task.  The CPLD chip alone will take care of everything you need in 1 IC, for a very cheap price.

As tcrosley mentioned, using 5 NOT gates in series will get you about 70 MHz, and from there you need to divide it down.  It almost certainly won't be 70 MHz though and will depend on which CPLD you select if you do and you'd of course need to calculate based on its respective propagation delay.

Using 23 flip-flops as dividers in series will divide that down to 8.34 Hz, and using 29 will get you 0.13 Hz.

From what I have heard, CPLD's typically contain 1 flip-flop per macrocell, thus you need at least 29 macrocells.

In fact [one of Lattice Semi's cheapest options](http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/Documents/Solutions/Packaging%20Solutions/ispMACH4000ZE%20Family%20Data%20Sheet1022.pdf) which comes in at $1.20 per chip has 32 macrocells.

And last but certainly not least, you can **easily** change the design and thus frequency of your oscillator by simply uploading new code, no need to rewire anything.

**Edit**

And actually in this case you wouldn't even need to use any logic elements to create the inverters as many CPLD's already have clock elements on them.  Just code up the clock to connect to your chain of dividers and send the output to your I/O.